# Input 0 is incompatible with layer when using dataset.batch

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I gave the following code which runs fine.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Reshape, Dropout, \
    BatchNormalization, Activation, Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
HEIGHT = 39
WIDTH = 39
CHANNELS = 2
SCALE_FACTOR = 4
VAL_SPLIT = 0.1
TRAIN_SPLIT = 0.8
TEST_SPLIT = 0.1
SEED = 1
BUFFER_SIZE = 100
LR = 1e-4
BATCH_SIZE = 2

INP_LOW = (HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS)

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
    
    
def resize_and_rescale(low, high):

    high = tf.image.resize(high, 
                           (HEIGHT, WIDTH),
                           preserve_aspect_ratio=False)
    return low, high


def split_train_test_val(ds,
                         seed,
                         train_split=TRAIN_SPLIT, 
                         val_split=VAL_SPLIT, 
                         test_split=TEST_SPLIT,
                         shuffle=True, 
                         shuffle_size=BUFFER_SIZE):                       
    assert (train_split + test_split + val_split) == 1
    
    ds_size = len(ds)
    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(shuffle_size, 
                        reshuffle_each_iteration=False,
                        seed=seed)
    
    train_size = int(train_split * ds_size)
    val_size = int(val_split * ds_size)
    test_size = int(test_split * ds_size)
    
    train_ds = ds.take(train_size)
    test_ds = ds.skip(train_size)
    val_ds = test_ds.skip(test_size)
    test_ds = test_ds.take(test_size)
    
    return train_ds, val_ds, test_ds

def prepare(ds, shuffle=False):
    
    ds = ds.map(resize_and_rescale, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    ds = ds.cache()
    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=BUFFER_SIZE)
  
    #ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    #ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
   
    return ds

def data_gen(low_res, high_res):
    
    dataset_low = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(low_res)
    dataset_high = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(high_res)
    
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset_low, dataset_high))
    
    train_ds, val_ds, test_ds = split_train_test_val(dataset,
                                                     SEED,
                                                     train_split=TRAIN_SPLIT, 
                                                     val_split=VAL_SPLIT, 
                                                     test_split=TEST_SPLIT,
                                                     shuffle=True, 
                                                     shuffle_size=BUFFER_SIZE)

   
    train_ds = prepare(train_ds, shuffle=True)
    val_ds = prepare(val_ds)
    test_ds = prepare(val_ds)
    return train_ds, val_ds, test_ds


def build_model(lr):
    inp = Input(lr)
    x = Dense(16)(inp)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(CHANNELS, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')(x)
    output = Activation('tanh')(x)
    model = Model(inp, output)
    return model


low = np.load('low.npy')
high = np.load('high.npy')

train_ds, val_ds, test_ds = data_gen(low, high)

model = build_model(INP_LOW)
model.compile(loss=['mse'],
              optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LR))

train_low, train_high = tf.data.experimental.get_single_element(train_ds.batch(len(train_ds)))

history = model.fit(train_low,
                    train_high,
                    epochs=2,
                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

But when I try to use :

```
 ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
  ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
```

in the `prepare` function and at the same time, I ommit the `batch_size` in fit:

```
history = model.fit(train_low,
                    train_high,
                    epochs=2)
```

I am receiving:

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_2: expected shape=(None, 39, 39, 2), found shape=(32, 2, 39, 39, 2)

You can find the data [here](https://easyupload.io/m/vt1mgy)

I would expect, since I remove the batch size from fit , to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `tf.data.Dataset` in `model.fit`, you should provide only the `x` argument of `model.fit`, with the assumption that your `tf.data.Dataset` returns a tuple `(input_features, targets)`.

You can read more in the [documentation of `keras.Model.fit`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit). Here's an excerpt with the relevant info:

> **Args**
>
> - `x`:    Input data. It could be:
>
>   - A `tf.data` dataset. Should return a tuple of either (inputs, targets) or (inputs, targets, sample_weights).
> - `y`:    If x is a dataset, generator, or `keras.utils.Sequence` instance, `y`
>   should not be specified (since targets will be obtained from `x`).

Assuming that `train_high` are your input features, and `train_low` are your targets, you should simply call `model.fit(train_ds, epochs=2)`, and skip the line

```
train_low, train_high = tf.data.experimental.get_single_element(train_ds.batch(len(train_ds)))
```